# Model for extracting common context from a similar cluster of sentence

Tags: deep-learning, nlp

I have multiple clusters of similar sentence embeddings (one cluster holding one type of similar sentences)

Is there any unsupervised model that can extract the common context from each cluster in:

- a dense embedding or
- in a sentence format altogether

I am gonna use BERT to evaluate the dense sentence embedding and apply hierarchical clustering to create the clusters (I haven't evaluated how well it is gonna work yet), then apply your suggested model to extract the common context.
P.S. I would be thankful if you could provide the model for the second option.